# What is default notification background color for all android versions?

Tags: android, background, notifications

Different Android versions have different default notification background color. I use custom notification layouts and I need to know what is default notification background color for all android versions (from 8 to 23). I didn´t find any list where this can be found. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use custom layout why the default color matters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can get such a list as it varies for different Versions/devices, as the documentation states:

> Always use style resources for the text of a custom notification. The background color of the notification can vary across different devices and versions, and using style resources helps you account for this. Starting in Android 2.3, the system defined a style for the standard notification layout text. If you use the same style in applications that target Android 2.3 or higher, you'll ensure that your text is visible against the display background.

From the source code you can see how it's set:

```
protected void applyLegacyRowBackground(StatusBarNotification sbn, View content) {
    if (sbn.notification.contentView.getLayoutId() !=
            com.android.internal.R.layout.notification_template_base) {
        int version = 0;
        try {
            ApplicationInfo info = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(sbn.pkg, 0);
            version = info.targetSdkVersion;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException ex) {
            Slog.e(TAG, "Failed looking up ApplicationInfo for " + sbn.pkg, ex);
        }
        if (version > 0 && version < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            content.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification_row_legacy_bg);
        } else {
            content.setBackgroundResource(com.android.internal.R.drawable.notification_bg);
        }
    }
}
```